# Is it possible to create plugin on non magento module?

Tags: magento2, plugin, graphql

Is it possible to create plugin on non magento module? for example for webonyx/graphql-php

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors and so on are also generated for non-magento modules, means:

Plugins, but also preferences, argument preferences, proxies, factories all work for non-magento modules.

So **short answer: yes**